# How to efficiently join 2 dataframes by comparing their column values

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes m_df & s_df :-

```
// m_df Schema

root
 |-- column_A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_B: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_C: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_D: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_E: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_F: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_G: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_H: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- m_id: string (nullable = false)

+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|column_A|column_B|column_C|column_D|column_E|column_F|column_G|                  id|                m_id|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     101|      16|      18|   RANDY|    ANDY|     101|      16|420d6da5-036a-401...|35d2e759-5b94-485...|
|     102|      27|      18|   RANDY|    ANDY|     101|      16|520d6da6-036a-401...|45d2e759-5b94-485...|
|     103|      25|      18|   RANDY|    ANDY|     101|      16|620d6da5-036a-401...|55d2e759-5b94-485...|
|     104|       7|       8|   MANDY|    ANDY|     110|     160|720d6da5-036a-401...|75d2e759-5b94-485...|
|     105|       9|      80|   MANDY|    ANDY|      11|      12|920d6da5-036a-401...|85d2e759-5b94-485...|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+


// s_df Schema - Renamed the fields to help with the join

root
 |-- s_column_C: string (nullable = true)
 |-- s_column_D: string (nullable = true)
 |-- s_column_E: string (nullable = true)
 |-- s_column_F: string (nullable = true)
 |-- s_column_G: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- s_id: string (nullable = false)

+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|s_column_C|s_column_D|s_column_E|s_column_F|s_column_G|                 _id|                s_id|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|        18|     RANDY|      ANDY|       101|        16|420d6da5-036a-401...|9ee2e759-5b94-485...|
|         8|     MANDY|      ANDY|       110|       160|720d6da5-036a-401...|3ed2e759-5b94-485...|
|        80|     MANDY|      ANDY|        11|        12|920d6da5-036a-401...|24d2e759-5b94-485...|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I want to join both `s_df` & `m_df` dataframes (PySpark) in a such way that:

1. Every m_id should have one s_id.
2. Every s_id should have multiple m_id's mapped to it.

`Expected Result :`

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|                m_id|                s_id|column_C|s_column_C|column_D|s_column_D|column_E|s_column_E|column_F|s_column_F|column_G|s_column_G|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|35d2e759-5b94-485...|9ee2e759-5b94-485...|      18|        18|   RANDY|     RANDY|    ANDY|      ANDY|     101|       101|      16|        16|
|45d2e759-5b94-485...|9ee2e759-5b94-485...|      18|        18|   RANDY|     RANDY|    ANDY|      ANDY|     101|       101|      16|        16|
|55d2e759-5b94-485...|9ee2e759-5b94-485...|      18|        18|   RANDY|     RANDY|    ANDY|      ANDY|     101|       101|      16|        16|
|75d2e759-5b94-485...|3ed2e759-5b94-485...|       8|         8|   MANDY|     MANDY|    ANDY|      ANDY|     110|       110|     160|       160|
|85d2e759-5b94-485...|24d2e759-5b94-485...|      80|        80|   MANDY|     MANDY|    ANDY|      ANDY|      11|        11|      12|        12|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
```

Now, I can join both `m_df` & `s_df` dataframes by checking each of the m_df.column_C values with one value s_df.s_column_C and map s_id to `m_df` i.e. using a UDF (PySpark).

But I know that custom UDF is usually inefficient, so I was looking for a better way of doing this join.

How can I solve this issue efficiently?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are looking for? I mean, if you proceed like this, you intend to reach something, and I do not understand yet. Maybe also add input data would make the process clearer. At this stage, I wonder why you split, you could use DropDuplicates from the initial dataframe, and what's the final join criteria (and which duplicates will be actually removed at the end)

Comment: My apologies @Christophe, I'm looking to join two dataframes in PySpark by comparing their column values. I have updated the question, hopefully it will not confuse others.

Comment: If i understand DropDuplicates() correctly and use it on a few columns, then i'll end up loosing the other column values like m_df.columnA & m_df.columnB. I want to retain those column values. Final join criteria =>  col('column_C') == col('s_column_C') & col('column_D') == col('s_column_D') & col('column_E') == col('s_column_E') & col('column_F') == col('s_column_F') where Every m_id should have one s_id & Every s_id should have multiple m_id's mapped to it.

Comment: If your problem is "just" to keep all columns by dropping duplicates, you should try because I'm 99% sure you will keep all columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m_s_df = m_df.join(s_df, on=(m_df.column_C == s_df.s_column_C)
                             & (m_df.column_D == s_df.s_column_D)
                             & (m_df.column_E == s_df.s_column_E)
                             & (m_df.column_F == s_df.s_column_F)
                             & (m_df.column_G == s_df.s_column_G),
                         how='left')
```

I got the mapping between m_df & s_df dataframes using the left join mentioned above.

'LEFT' join on all of the common columns between 2 dataframes satisfies the following criteria :

1. Every m_id should have one s_id.
2. Every s_id should have multiple m_id's mapped to it.

Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.